# How to see MTurk tasks individually page by page?

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

I'm using Mturk for the first time, and I had a quite simple question.

I have 6 different short essays that we want people to read, and I want only one essay to be presented at a time on the page.

To do so, would I set "Number of assignments per properties" as 6 in the "Enter Properties" tab, and have 6 separate `<crowd-form></crowd-form>` with each essay within the open/close of crowd forms?

However, from my preview version, it shows all the essays in one page, and wasn't sure if it was just a matter of preview thing or not.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to do each story as a different HIT, rather than trying to put 6 on one "page." Is there a reason all 6 need to be presented at the same time?